# Blackhole engine optimization / table locking issue

Tags: mysql, optimization, database-tuning

I am adding a lot of rows to a table with BLACKHOLE engine. Processlist shows that a lot of queries are waiting for table lock. MySQL profiler shows that INSERTs to that table are the biggest cause of why my DB is overloaded. I have already optimized columns and data. I don't have any large fields, etc. Could you advice me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using this engine and, moreover, are trying to optimize work with it?